# How can I create Presto app in X-Author for excel

Tags: excel, salesforce

I want to create Presto app in X-Author excel and I have done all configuration setup for this as well I have made Presto app in excel but In salesforce when I click on the button to call Presto at that time I get an error "Failed to export data to Excel" here 'Excel' is the output type.

[image]

and after clicking continue I got this Error:

[image]

I am quite new in X-author so don't know the actual flow of presto app and how excel formulas will use into Salesforce.  Can anyone help me for this?

Comment: This is not a please-write-the-code-for-me type of forum, you need to provide us with what you have done so far.

Comment: @Ibo Thanks for the reply but there is no coding needed to create presto app in excel. all I have used is just standard salesforce point and clicks for the detail button and excel functionality to create app.